# What is the formula for conversion ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got a simple math problem.I am trying the find the conversion ratio between two symbol.Let assume that

> A : B
>
> 1 : 100 (1 A = 100 B)
>
> A : C
>
> 1 : 300 (1 A = 300 C)
>
> B : C
>
> 1 : ? (1 B = ? C)

What is the C equivalent of 1 B? and what is the formula used to calculate such problem? I wanted to find the **r** value.

> B value X r = C value

Answer (score 1):

For each A you get $100$ B and $300$ C

Comment: I wanted to know how many C would I get for 1 B ?

Comment: All you have to do is divide by $100$.  1B=3C

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail ?

Comment: What detail? 100C=300B:100 1C=3B

Comment: How do you get 100 C = 300 B ?

Comment: 1A=100B and 1A=300C So 100B=300C

Comment: I know get the point you are making. Can I assume that r=(Value of A:C/Value of A:B) . r=(300/100) , r=3  in B value X r = C value.